# Show the sigma algebra containing $\{2n,2n+2,2n+4,..\}$ is uncountable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am asked the following:

1) Show that for any family of subsets $A$ of $\Omega$ there is a smallest $\sigma - $algebra containing $A$.

2) Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sigma algebra in the space $\Omega$ of natural numbers. Let $A_n \in \mathcal{F}$ where $$A_n = \{2n,2n+2,\dots \}, n = 1,2,\dots $$

Show that $\mathcal{F}$ has uncountably many members.

I have completed 1), and I am on 2). Here is what I have tried:

As $A_n \in \mathcal{F}$ we have $(\Omega \backslash A_{n+1}) \cap A_n = \{2n \} \in \mathcal{F}$. Hence, as $\mathcal{F}$ is a sigma algebra, any set of even natural numbers is in $\mathcal{F}$. Now I wanted to use part 1) of the question to construct an infinite set of even natural numbers, and create a bijection $f$ to $[0,1]$ to show it is uncountable.

Any ideas how I can use part 1)?

Answer (score 1):

The set $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ is also uncountable. You should try to show that every subset of the set of natural, even numbers is in $\mathcal F$.

Comment: I don't understand how this helps me use part 1 of the question (which is what I am asking).

Comment: There is a smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\{2\}$, $\{4\}$, $\{6\}$, ...

Comment: OK Thanks, with that in mind, I let $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n/2^n$ where $a_n = 1$ if $2n \in \mathcal{A}$ and $0$ otherwise, where I denote $\mathcal{A}$ as teh samllest sigma algebra containing the even natural numbers. I claim this is a bijection with $[0,1]$. Is this enough? I don't really understand how to proceed with your answer.